# Spring - OAuth2AccessTokenSupport Override rest template custom SSLSocketFactory

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

I'm using `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider` to get the `OAuth` access token for client credentials. However, the `accessTokenURI` is `https`. 
what is the recommended way to override the default `RestTemplate` to provide a custom `SSLSocketFactory`.

The `RestTemplate` on `OAuth2AccessTokenSupport` is marked private without any setters.

Answer (score 0):

ah never mind,
you can set the reqestFactory on the RestTemplate.

code is as follows,

```
Create the Request Factory,

RequestConfig timeoutConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT).build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                        .setDefaultRequestConfig(timeoutConfig)                      .disableCookieManagement().setMaxConnPerRoute(CONNECTION_MAX).setMaxConnTotal(CONNECTION_MAX).build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);


 ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
        accessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```